# Mistakes you should not do in calculation of limits

Tags: calculus

So I have to calculate the limit of $\frac{\cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}{\cos(x)}$ when $x \rightarrow 0$.

So I know that $\frac{1}{\cos(x)}=1$ when $x \rightarrow 0$

I also know that  $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ $-1 < \cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) < 1$.

And thanks to the fact that:

Given two series $a_{n}$ convergent and $b_{n}$ is blocked then:

$\lim_{n \rightarrow 0} (a_{n}b_{n}) = (\lim_{n \rightarrow 0} a_{n}) (\lim\sup_{n \rightarrow 0} b_{n})$

we can say that $\lim\frac{\cos(\frac{1}{x})}{\cos(x)} = (1)(1) = 1$ when $x \rightarrow 0$.

But this is not true because there is no limit to that expression.

I know that the theorem relates to series and not functions but as far as I know in this case it is the same and besides I know according to the same sentence that :

when $x \rightarrow 0$ $\lim (x\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right))=(\lim (x)(\lim\sup (\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right))) = 0$

So where is my mistake ?

What am I doing wrong ?

How can I know I can use arithmetic of limits correct ?

Thanks in advanced !!

Comment: What do you mean by $b_n$ is "blocked"? Perhaps the theorem you're thinking of is that if $a_n \to 0$ and $b_n$ is bounded, then $a_n b_n \to 0$.

Comment: Yes, I ment bounded. is the theorem I wrote is not true for function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are incorrect when you say that $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to 0} a_n b_n = \lim_{n \to 0}a_n \limsup_{n \to 0} b_n.$ This is not true, and the example you give acts as a counterexample.

Comment: "You are incorrect when you say ... " - you mean this is not true for function but to series it is true or it is always incorrect ? And does it in the second example ?

Comment: @wantToLearn: As it's written, it's not true in any setting. The closest fix I can think of is when $a_n \to 0$ and $b_n$ is bounded, whereby $a_nb_n \to 0$, as in Dirichlet's test. But this is a vastly weaker statement than the one you wrote.